# Are the two infima equal?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative) or an algebra over some field with a norm defined on it and let $I$ be an ideal in $R$. Let $a,b \in R$. Does it hold that

$\inf_{i,j \in I}\|ab + ai + bj + ij\| = \inf_{i' \in I} \|ab + i'\|$?

Basically I am asking if

$$ \inf_{i,j \in I } \|(a+i)(b+j)\| = \inf_{i \in I} \|ab + i\|$$

I have tried a few examples (quite a few) and it seems to always hold. But I also tried to prove it and I couldn't so that even now after trying for some time I still don't know whether it holds or not. Please could someone help me?

I could prove one direction:

For all $a,b \in R$ and $i,j \in I$,  $ai + bj + ij \in I$ and therefore 
$$ \inf_{i \in I} \|ab + i\| \le \inf_{i,j \in I} \|ab + ai + bj + ij\|$$

Comment: Any more information about the ideal or the ring? Does the ring have neutral multiplicative element?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Any example will do you may choose $R$ and $I$ as you wish. The example with the trivial norm in the new answer seems to provide proof that equality does not always hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring with the trivial norm: $\|f\|=1$ when $f \neq 0 $. (This example works with more interesting norms, but I thought I'd make it simple.)

Let $I = (xy)$.  Then $\inf_{i,j\in I}\|(x+i)(y+j)\| = 1$, because $x+i$ and $y+j$ are both nonzero.  But $\inf_{i\in I} \|xy+i\| = 0$, since $-xy\in I$.

So equality is not met in this case.  In other words, the induced norm on $k[x,y]/(xy)$ is not multiplicative (it can't be, because the Berkovich space has more than one Shilov point... but that's another story).

Answer (score 2):

As $I$ is an ideal or $R$, then $ai+bj+ij\in I$, ($a,b\in R$, $i,j\in I$), and hence the second infimum does not exceed the first one.

However, if $I$ does not contain $1$ (the neutral element of multiplication), I do not see how an arbitrary element $i'$ of $I$ can be expressed as $ai+bj+ij$, in order to obtain that the first infimum does not exceed the second one.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example where the infima are not equal?